# assert that an operation raises a Stopiteration

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, python-unittest

I have a generator that I want to confirm has ended (at a certain point in the program. I am using unittest in python 2.7

```
# it is a generator whould have only one item
item = it.next()
# any further next() calls should raise StopIteration
self.assertRaises(StopIteration, it.next())
```

But it fails with the message

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_productspider_parse_method (__main__.TestMyMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myName/tests/__main__.py", line 94, in test_my_method
    self.assertRaises(StopIteration, it.next())
StopIteration

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the method itself instead of calling the method. In other word, drop the parentheses.

```
self.assertRaises(StopIteration, it.next)
```

Or you can use it as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
    it.next()
```